# Cannot import ttf font in Monogame

Tags: fonts, xna, monogame, truetype

I'm working on a Monogame project, and for that I need to import ttf fonts into XNA.

In the Monogame Pipeline Tool, whenever I try to build the font files, an error occurs and tell that
`Could not find an default importer for 'C:/path/to/ttf/file/file.ttf`

I used a file.spritefont and modified it like said in the monogame documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would be glad to help if you provided a bit more info, make sure to include these things: The contents of file.spritefont, and the contents of the content directory.

These things might be causing the problem:

- File.ttf might not be in /Contnet
- file.ttf might not be liked to file.spritefont

Have a nice day!